# Passing variable from django template to view

Tags: django

I'm building my first site with django 1.7 and am having a hard time figuring out how to pass a variable from a click to a view. My GET is also empty.

My template has a table with Facebook Account IDs, when clicked should show a list of Facebook pages that user Admins.

My template:

```
{% for SocialAccount in accountlist %}
   <tr>
      <td><a href="{% url 'INI:fbpages' %}">{{ SocialAccount.uid }}</a></td>
      <td>{{ SocialAccount.extra_data.first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ SocialAccount.extra_data.last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ SocialAccount.extra_data.email }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and my view:

```
def fbpages(request, fbuser):
    djuser = request.user.id
    context = RequestContext(request)
    fbuser = 1234634
    pagelist = facebook.pages(request, djuser, fbuser)
    blocks = {'title': 'Facebook Pages',
          'pagelist': pagelist}
    return render(request, "initiative/ListFBPages.html", blocks)
```

I could do this easily if I put the ID in the URL but I don't want to expose a page/user ID in the url. I feel like there's an easy solution but I haven't figured it out.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: There's no special way to do this in Django. It's just basic HTTP. Use a form. Don't want it in the URL? Use a `POST` request.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can only send data to Django views from the template with 4 different methods. In your case you will probably only be able to use option 1 and 4 if you don't want the information in the URL.

**1. Post**

So you would submit a form with value.

```py
# You can retrieve your code in your views.py via
request.POST.get('value')
```

**2. Query Parameters**

You would pass `//localhost:8000/?id=123`.

```py
# You can retrieve your code in your views.py via
request.GET.get('id')
```

**3. From the URL (See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) for example)**

You would pass `//localhost:8000/12/results/`.

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns(
    # ...
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ...
)
```

In your views:

```py
# views.py
# To retrieve (question_id)
def detail(request, question_id):
    # ...
    return HttpResponse("blahblah")
```

**4. [Session (via cookie)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/)**

Downside of using session is you would have had to pass it to the view or set it earlier.

```py
# views.py
# Set the session variable
request.session['uid'] = 123456

# Retrieve the session variable
var = request.session.get('uid')
```

Comment: Thank you Jester. I think I will go with option 1. I was using urls previously and it worked well but I don't want users to manipulate the url to see other user's pages and linked accounts. I tried to experiment with the permission required decorator but I think my skills are too beginner for that still.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on the 2nd method? More specifically, how can I set query parameters (if the '?...' is that) in a template?

Comment: The 2nd method is passing a variable through the url paramater. For example if you did. http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/?id=200 you can grab the id variable by using request.GET.get('id'). In this case request.GET.get('id') would return "200".

Comment: Good answer.  Although I wish you would have been more specific with method 1.  I'm looking for elsewhere for instructions on using method 1 but haven't figured it out.

Comment: I still don't see how to pass it in a nice way without ? foo

Answer (score 3):

To add to JJK's answer, here's the detailed way to pass a variable from template to view using form.

**Template :**

```
<form action="{% url 'INI:fbpages' SocialAccount.uid %}" method="post">
..
</form>
```

Above, 'INI:fbpages' is the url pattern name defined in urls.py

SocialAccount.uid is the variable that you want to pass to the view.

Note that the double curly braces used in variable rendering in django templates are not used here.

**View :**

This variable can be directly accessed in the view as the fbuser command argument

```
def fbpages(request, fbuser):
..
```

Answer (score 0):

We also use like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
       path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
       path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
       path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
       path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

Comment: How do we access year (for example) in the view?

Comment: It would be an additional argument in the view method (works in class based views too). E.G. `def my_view(request, year):`