# Django 1.10 - Issue passing value from Template to View

Tags: html, django, forms, python-2.7, post

I am having an issue when it cmoes to passing variables from templates to views. Even though I am able to pass variables from view to template, I canot seem to get it right. I have looked at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153593/passing-variable-from-django-template-to-view).

Following the Django docs I created a `forms.py` script as follows:

### forms.py

GNU nano 2.7.4                    File: forms.py

```
from django import forms

class TactForm(forms.Form):
        tacttime = forms.CharField(label='Tact Time', max_length=100)
```

### Updated View

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from lineoee.models import Lineoee31

from .forms import TactForm

def details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TactForm(request.POST)
            print(form)
    else:
            form = TactForm()

    context = {'form' : form}

    return render(request, 'linedetails/index.html',context)
```

### Updated Template

```
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'details' %}">
                    {% csrf_token  %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <label for="tacttime">Tact Time: </label>
                    <input id="tacttime" type="text" name="tacttime" value ="60">
                    <input type="submit" value="OK">
            <form>
```

### Updated URLS

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from lineoee.views import index
from lineoee.views import details

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'lineoee/$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'linedetails/', details, name='details'),
]
```

Still, no errors and no values passed to the view.

---

### EDIT

I am now getting some data on pressing the OK button, however it is not what I was expecting. I want to be able to retrieve the **text entered into the `input` field. How can I do this?**

> "POST /linedetails/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24580
>
> ```
> <tr><th><label for="id_tacttime">Tact Time:</label></th><td><input 
> type="text" name="tacttime" value="60" required id="id_tacttime" 
> maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
> ```

Comment: any error you are getting? most probably  you will get the csrf validation error.

Comment: No errors whatsoever. Page is rendered accordingly but nothing is printed to console when pressing submit.

Comment: can you past the console log after post?

Comment: Can you share your URL that's pointing to that view?

Comment: request.POST['textfield']

Comment: @marin, where should I include that? Can you post a link or explain further please? I have edited my code as suggested by other stack overflow answers.

Comment: You're posting to the wrong URL. `<form method="POST" action="/details">` should be `<form method="POST" action="/linedetails">`

Comment: @HigorRossato you are right. Edited accordingly but I am still unable to see any changes on pressing submit.

Comment: @amankumar not sure if I understood you correctly, but there is no output to cnosole after post.

Comment: have you print the request.POST, please print that see data is coming or not

Comment: No data is coming

Comment: Few things: 

1 - Try to have a URL on Django standards `url(r'^archive/$', views.archive, name='news-archive')` 
2 - You apparently don't have a context variable to pass to the template. You need to define one: E.g `context = {'something': variable}` and also your return indentation is wrong. It should be 4 spaces inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Template**

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'details' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="adsfadsfas">
    </form>
</div>
```

**Views (EDITED)**

Whatever the name you use in your input on your HTML template, that's the key you're gonna use to get what comes in the `request.POST`. That's why you'd like to use `{{ form.field }}` in the template so you know beforehand the name of the fields you're expecting to come in the `request.POST`

```
def details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.POST)
            print(request.POST.get('tacttime')
            form = TactForm(request.POST)
            print(form)
    else:
            form = TactForm()

    return render(request, 'linedetails/index.html', context)
```

**URLS**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from lineoee.views import index
from lineoee.views import details

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'lineoee/$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'linedetails/', details, name='details'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, am in the process of trying this out. Agree with the views and urls, but don't understand the template part. What is `form.as_p`? Thanks

Comment: `as_p` is a method inside the form that renders the form as a p HTML tag. You can check it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Comment: I believe I updated everything as you suggest, but to no avail. No errors but nothing prints to the console.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but nothing happens too. Following the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) I think I have some confusion with the templates. In the tuturial it shows two separate templates. One with the `<input type="submit" value="OK">` line and another template with the `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` line

Comment: That's weird, I mean, you not get anything on your post. I, with this code, could get the post in and print the form. Have you tried to stop and start your server again? It sounds silly but who knows

Comment: Yes I have restarted my server multiplel times.

Comment: Should you assign form variable in view to variable context ? `return render(request, 'linedetails/index.html', {'form' : form})`

Comment: @SAZ, yes will update accordingly thanks. I will post a new edit showing some data I am receiving shortly.

Comment: @HigorRossato I am now able to print the form and receive the POST. However I am unable to specifically receive/extract the data which the user has entered. I updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
def details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            var = request.POST['textfield']
            print(var)
```

Comment: Tried this, nothing happens.