# Passing data to form (from POST and url)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm not sure how to pass data from a given object (profile) and from form (request.POST) to one model (many to many relation).

I have two models: Profile and Keyword. Users can define many profiles (for different subjects) and in each profile they can define many keywords (used later by a crawler). It is possible that the same keyword is in many profiles, and one profile can have many keywords.

Now, I have a view adding new profile to user, and in next step I want to add view adding keyword/keywords to this particular profile.

I'm passing a parameter foreign key - profile_id - via url, and I have build form from my model Keyword. Now I have problem with passing both of them to my function.

models.py

```
class Profiles (models.Model):
    id_profile = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=120, default=' ')


class Keywords (models.Model):
    id_keyword = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id_profile = models.ManyToManyField(Profiles)
```

template

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit"> <a href="{% url 'new_keyword' profile_id=object.id_profile %}">new keyword </a></button>
```

urls.py

```
path('profile_detail/<int:pk>/', users_view.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name = 'profile_detail'),
path('new_keyword/<profile_id>/', users_view.NewKeyword, name = 'new_keyword'),
```

views.py

```
def newKeyword(request):
    form = NewKeyword(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form.is_valid()
        form.save()
        return redirect('profile')
    return render(request, 'users/new_keyword.html', {'form': form})
```

Now I have

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile_id'
```

I understand that I have to somehow overwrite **init**() to accept profile_id, but I'm not sure how.

---

ok, thank you for you answer. I have changed my code, but now I have different problem:The Keywords could not be created because the data didn't validate.

```
def newKeyword(request):
    context = {}
    context['id_profile'] = request.POST.get('id_profile', None)
    form = NewKeyword(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form.is_valid()
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        obj.id_profile.add(context['id_profile'])
        obj.save()
        return redirect('profile')
    return render(request, 'users/new_keyword.html', {'form': form})
```

and template in previous page:

```
 <form method="POST" name="newkeyword" value='keyword'>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> New keyword </legend>
        {{ form | crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit">create</button>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Looks like after clicking a button on page profile (in order to go to view: creating keyword) I use method POST to send parameter, hence my 'If statement' runs...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve GET data.

```
def newKeyword(request, profile_id):
```

and you can retrieve that parameter with this way but for POST data,
you can use;

```
request.GET.get('profile_id') # GET method
request.POST.get('profile_id') # POST method
```

and you don't need to edit url for this.

related question:
[Passing variable from django template to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153593/passing-variable-from-django-template-to-view)