# Having issues with getting my back-end data to the front-end (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a blog in which I need a comment section(first project ever, 3 weeks into Python/Django). So far I've created 2 models(Blog which is the main and Comment which is linked with a foreign key to the Blog) but for some reason, I can't find the proper way to display the information from the Comment model into my HTML section.

I've tried with dictionaries, rewrote the models and the views multiple times(due to different youtube videos that I found) but nothing seems to work properly.

These are my models :

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Blog\'s title', max_length=100, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField('Enter your blog\'s url', blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Date and time on publication', 
    blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    thumb = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, 
    default='default_blog_icon.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.content[:50] + ' ' +'...'

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='comments')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approved(self):
        self.approved = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

The views :

```
def index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    args = {'blogs': blogs, 'comments': comments}    
    return render(request, "blog/index.html", args)

def blog_details(request, slug):
    slug_url = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_details.html', {'blog_info': slug_url})
```

And the HTML :

```
    {% for blog in blogs %}
        <div class="bloggy">
            <h3><a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug %}">{{ 
blog.title }}</a></h3>
            <img src ="/media/{{ blog.thumb }}">
            <p>{{ blog.snippet }}</p>
            <p>Posted on {{ blog.date }}</p>
            <p>{{ comments }}</p>
            <p>{{ Comments.Blog.get_user }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.user }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.created }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.approved }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So far the only thing that I am getting on the front end is the `{{ comments }}` which is giving me the username that I set. Apart from that nothing else is showing.

I need somehow to display the username, the body of the comment(the content itself) and the date.

Any help, feedback or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Do you really want all the comments for each blog on the index page?

Comment: No, but as soon as I found out to display the data I will put them in the other page. The problem is how can I get the data from the back end to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the comment for each blog this way:

In your views.py:

```
def index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all().prefetch_related('comments').order_by('-date')
    args = {'blogs': blogs}    
    return render(request, "blog/index.html", args)
```

Then in your template, you can change the HTML to this:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
    <div class="bloggy">
        <h3><a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug %}">{{blog.title}}</a></h3>
        <img src ="/media/{{ blog.thumb }}">
        <p>{{ blog.snippet }}</p>
        <p>Posted on {{ blog.date }}</p>
        {% for comment in blog.comments.all %}
            <p>{{ comment.blog.get_user }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.user }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.created }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.approved }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Now if I want to get that information and display it on another page what is the best way? Should I create a new function : def blog_comments(request):
    comments_data = Blog.objects.all().prefetch_related('comments')
    args_two = {'comments_data': comments_data}
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_details.html', {'comments': args_two}) and another for cycle or ?

Comment: If you want to create a new page with similar content, I'll recommend creating a new view for that URL. You can try [Django's poll app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/) if you're new with Django. If you want to send some data from one template to another, then you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153593/passing-variable-from-django-template-to-view)