# How to change context in Django using html buttons

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So i have 2 models and 1 is associated with other. I have buttons corresponding to a model and i want to pull the data when pressed on the responding button. How can i manipulate context in view (i am using function views) and then update html using buttons with their related context. I don't want to use Javascript. How can i do it with django, or is it possible ?

Comment: please share your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might need to further examine the underlying basics of how Django views work. Consider referencing the Django Docs tutorial. Specifically, [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/), where they start having "views that actually do something".

---

Having said that, for a more direct answer, it's hard to answer precisely, because you're not really indicating what you're trying to accomplish. Other than a vague "user presses button and magic happens". So I'll try to explain the overall Django process, to hopefully help guide you in the correct direction:

Django views are, effectively, how a standard/default Django project processes data, and then serves some template/page response back to the user, based on said data. Accessing a view is handled backend, on the server itself. So by definition, accessing a Django function requires a page reload, to show a new template/page response, based on whatever data changed based on the user's button press.

If you want an in-place page change, without reloading the page, then the only way to accomplish this is via JavaScript. Furthermore, if you need to prevent page reloading AND notify the server of some data update, then you're likely looking at something like [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and websocket communication. That very quickly gets much more complicated, and I wouldn't recommend that if you're already unfamiliar with Django (as your initial question seems to imply).

---

As far as what you seem to be getting at, of a question of "how do I change a page using views, after a user presses some button", the basic answer is such:

1. You serve the user some in initial page from some view. You seem to be doing this step already.
2. On the page the user sees, there are one or more buttons. These buttons should include  tags, that might look something like `<a href="{% url 'my_app:my_page' <some_param> %}">Example Link</a>`. In this case, replace `my_app:my_page` with the actual internal url to access the desired page. Replace `<some_param>` with the desired data/value you wish to change, based on the user pressing said button. See [template urls in the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for further info.
3. From here, the user's browser is now submitting some value based on some button press. The server will now attempt to receive this. You need to update your view to be able to receive said value, and then run view logic accordingly. For this, I once again recommend examining the [Django Docs tutorial, part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/). Alternatively, you can reference something such as [this other stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153593/passing-variable-from-django-template-to-view).

Note: The above stack overflow answer also mentions things like "POST" and "form values". You can also have the user submit data via a Django form, in which case the user enters/changes information not just from "pressing a singular button", but also from "typing information and/or manipulating form widgets". Generally input from forms is more meaningful and detailed than what you can get from a single button press.

Having said all that, without further explanation or some code on your part, it's hard to give more concrete advice, based on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. But this should at least gave you a starting place for further research.